# The REST API is not enabled for this Organization (Salesforce API using databasedotcom gem) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce, databasedotcom-gem

I recently integrated Salesforce API via databasedotcom gem to my Rails 3.2 app.

Also, there's a background job for the synchronization of data.

Upon, logging in my Professional edition Salesforce account, the Resque job failed and it displayed this error...

```
Class
Jobs::Salesforce::Contact
Arguments
1
Exception
Databasedotcom::SalesForceError
Error
The REST API is not enabled for this Organization.
```

How will I be able to enable API even for Professional Editions?

I've tried to use Developer Edition and got no problem.

Are there specific editions that are allowed to use REST API in Salesforce?

How about trial version of Professional Edition?

Thanks. And Have a great day!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By any chance are you on Developer Edition? verify that you have the “API Enabled” permission.

In case of Professional Edition you may have to contact Salesforce support to enable API.

For EE and UE it is automatically enabled.

below are the two links that may help you

https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom/issues/49

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gnjCAAQ

Comment: Where can I see the “API Enabled” permission option? I am using Developer edition for the connected app.

Comment: API Enabled permission will be on the Users Permission Section in the Profile.

API Enabled option will be there only for Users of Profile System Administrator or Cloned profiel of System Administrator.

https://na4.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_userperms.htm

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gr7kAAA please follow it for more info

Comment: Voted already. So last question, I already set up the API enabled via Manage Users > Permission Set > System Permission . After that, the problem still persists... that would mean that there's no way to make it work for PE and GE right? Am I thinking the correct instinct?

Answer (score 0):

FYI: There is no option Rest API Enabled in Salesforce free trail version. I would suggest you to try Developer Edition which is also free for a time period by using click [this](https://developer.salesforce.com) link